# mount ext4 usb disk in /run/media/$USER/DISK-LABEL as user but not as root

Tags: shell-script, systemd, automounting

I have found a couple of script using systemd to mount an usb disk.

- one udev script
- one systemd service script (which call the shell script passing the device name, the action to be done )
- one shell script in /usr/local/bin

My main problem is that the logged user is unknown in the shell script because it is not known in the systemd script.

I would like to mount the usb disk in /run/media/$(logname)/DISK-LABEL

Is there a solution ?

Any help is welcome